# Import error, can't find file - stackblitz React JS

Tags: reactjs, stackblitz

I'm working on a POC on stackblitz environment, while trying to import the app.tsx file, `Import error, can't find file:` getting this error in browser.

Below is my project link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kvyax9

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of typos/spelling mistakes in your imports.

In `index.tsx`, you have this import:

```
import App from './App';
```

whereas your `app` file exists as `app.tsx` not as `App.tsx`. You need to mention the filename correctly as

```
import App from './app';
```

Similarly, in `app.tsx`, all your imports are referencing incorrect filenames. Change them to this:

```
import A from './a';
import B from './b';
import C from './c';
import D from './d';
import './style';
```